# How to export directly in a Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, export

I want to export something directly in my Makefile so I did a rule like this one :

```
export: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./smthing/here
```

And then I call this rule in my `$(NAME)`

```
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
        $(export)
```

`$(OBJS)` is a simple rule to convert all my `.cpp` into `.o`.

`$(CXXFLAGS)` are my compiling flags : `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`

And so on for `$(LDFLAGS)` you got the point..

The problem here is that my export rule is done but it didn't exported what I expected. Why ? Can you help me ?

I got this if I don't do the export by hand in my terminal :

```
./cutom_prog: error while loading shared libraries: custom_lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: _"but it didn't exported what I expected"_ Could you please provide some more clarification about this in your question?

Comment: Well I got a shared linrary I must export. My binary will not run without this.

Comment: Put any error messages verbatim in the question please. The `$(NAME)` rule doesn't execute your binary BTW. You may need to add to that path at some installation script.

Comment: Error message added.

Comment: Yeah, but putting a rule isn't sufficient, it seems.

Comment: I even tried the 2 things @chattraed suggested to me below, but same error happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle exporting from Makefile, then try:

```
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
        @export MY_ENV_VAR=my_value; \
        $(CXX) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Exporting will only work if called in the same subshell with the command itself.

However, this solution is not going to work for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, because your intention is to update the parent process from `make`, which is not possible.

The workaround is to create a wrapper script that would:

- *build your application by calling* `make`
- *set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH*
- *launch your application*

Comment: Do you experience the same problem if you export prior to calling `make`? I mean: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/custom/path; make`

Comment: Yup, I got the same error message that I put in my question.

Comment: Ok, so what is your real target: exporting some environment variable from Makefile (as the title suggests) or just fixing the compilation process in any way?

Comment: I need to export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make it target to my own shared library. Because if I don't do so, my binary generated from the Makefile won't work.

Comment: Ok, so what is the path in which `custom_lib.so` actually resides?

Comment: It's in the same as the Makefile
`./custom_lib/lib2/libs`

Comment: Be aware, you must export the absolute path, not relative to your current working directory!

Comment: Well.. I can't really do that. My program must work with any computer so I can't do an absolute path because I can't know where people will put it. Or I should use `ENV` to get `pwd` ?

Comment: Check the updated answer, please. If your library resides in `./custom_lib/lib2/libs` and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the ONLY problem, then this solution should work. If it doesn't work, there are more problems than just setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: No I swear, it's still not working. I tried `        @LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(PWD)/custom_lib/lib2/libs; \`
And the same error message poping out. If I type the export in the term, it works.

Comment: Follow these steps: 1) export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your parent shell, even before calling `make`. 2) call make => things will probably not work. 3) Debug your problem, until you solve it. 4) After that, you move your export command back to Makefile.

Comment: 1) did my export. 2) calling make of the Makefile (is working, not warning, no errors, nothing). 3) Launching binary => Working fine.

Comment: Ok. Perfect. Then, it should be Makefile-related. Have you kept the backslash between `export` and `$(CXX)`, like shown in my example? It is the key part, it make things to happen in the same subshell.

Comment: Yes, I just copy pasted it, it's here.

Comment: Ok, then I suspect the following thing: some other target (not only `$(NAME)`) absolutely needs this export! So, try adding the same export line to all of your targets in the same manner (for debug).

Comment: Well the only line I got is `all: $(NAME)`

Comment: Oh wait ! When I do my convertion from .cpp to .o, it's compiling and here it needs the export ! Maybe I am wrong, but I think  it's coming from here !
`$(NAME): $(OBJS)`
But I can't do the export on this line, I'm forced to do it after this line.

Comment: Isn't `$(OBJS)` a target defined in your Makefile?

Comment: It's doing : `OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)`
And `SRCS = main.cpp` (And so one for all .cpp ...)

Comment: Let's continue in the chat window!

Comment: @nookonee: I've updated the answer, according to our offline findigs.

Comment: I validated your solution, again thanks for the time you spent with me yesterday :)

Comment: @nookonee: Thanks and welcome. Expecting more chances to interact on stackoverflow :)