# How to directly export LD_LIBRARY_PATH in makefile

Tags: c++, bash, makefile, shared-libraries

I want to export a shared library directly in my Makefile. So I went through stackoverflow and followed the steps listed on this page: [How to export directly in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830885/how-to-export-directly-in-a-makefile). But they didn't work for my Makefile.

If I export it(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) manually using the terminal, it works.
I want to know what is the correct approach to export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` directly using makefile.

I got this error if I don't do the export by hand in my terminal :
`./myProgram.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libcustom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

**Additional Information:**
The Application works fine if I first export using terminal, then make and run the `.exe`

Here is my **Makefile**:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11
LD       =  $(CXX) 
RM       =  rm

PLATFORM   = LINUX64

LIB        = /my_path/lib/
         
SO         = $(LIB)/libCustom.so
L1_SO      = $(LIB)/libCustom1.so

INC        = /my_path/inc
L1_INC     = /my_path/L1/C/inc
export: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/smthing/here:$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

EXE  = myProgram.exe
SRCS = myProgram.cpp
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp
.cpp.o :
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -I$(INC) -I$(L1_INC)

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
       @export MY_ENV_VAR=/smthing/here; \
       $(LD) -o $@ $(OBJS) -L$(LIB) -lCustom -lCustom1 -ldl -lrt -lz
       @echo make $(EXE) successful...

  clean:
       rm -fr *Log $(EXE) *.o
```

Comment: Do you intend to run your program by Makefile ??

Comment: Yes, I'm executing it through makefile

Comment: you do `make'` to build the program, then run it. They are not on same scope. The var you exported in Makefile is only valid in there

Comment: can you please tell me then how to export it in the same scope in which the program runs?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the example below

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11
LD       =  $(CXX) 
RM       =  rm

PLATFORM   = LINUX64

LIB        = /my_path/lib/
         
SO         = $(LIB)/libCustom.so
L1_SO      = $(LIB)/libCustom1.so

INC        = /my_path/inc
L1_INC     = /my_path/L1/C/inc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH += /smthing/here

EXE  = myProgram.exe
SRCS = myProgram.cpp
OBJS = ${SRCS:.cpp=.o}

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp
.cpp.o :
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -I$(INC) -I$(L1_INC)

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
       $(LD) -o $@ $(OBJS) -L$(LIB) -lCustom -lCustom1 -ldl -lrt -lz
       @echo make $(EXE) successful...
       ./$@

  clean:
       rm -fr *Log $(EXE) *.o
```

Comment: @nhatq, I just tried this but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: You may need to correct the path for LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The `./$@` is to execute the program in Makefile with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH set

Comment: I rechecked the path for LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I also tried using `./$@` for executing the program, but it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure the lib `libcustom.so` is already in the path ?? Can you show it ??

Comment: is it possible to change the environment variable of the shell in which `make` is called? Since, I'm trying to do that in the makefile.

Comment: What is your current error ?? Does the `export` work for you ??

Comment: It works for me when I use it to set the environment variables in the terminal, but when I use it in makefile, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't completely get what you want to resolve as well as I cannot replicate it . You set the env var by `export`. That will cause it in subsequent commands executed. In this case you call `make` and `program` in the same shell as sub-commands. The `export` in Makefile is only applicable inside the `make` . Anyway you can  try to print it Makefile `@echo $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: What I'm currently doing is - I'm compiling the program through makefile and then setting up the env variable through the terminal. This is a tedious process to set the env variable through terminal. So, I'm trying to set it through the makefile. But, since the env varibale set through makefile is only applicable inside the make and not in the terminal from which the make was called, so I'm getting error. The thing is, this env variable will be needed by the executable, so it is unable to recognise it as set from the current shell.

Comment: What I'm trying to find, is there a way to set the env variable for the terminal from which the make was called through the makefile?

Comment: I think no. To reach the target you will need to use Makefile to execute your program as well e.g. add a rule to run you binary then you can do like `make; make run`

Comment: I'm thinking to create a shell script for this now, since it can't be handled from makefile